# Why do I receive the error variable not in scope in this particular case?

Tags: haskell

When I create a .hs file with the following code and load it to ghci using `:l`, the file loads, but I receive the error `<interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: symbol` if I ask for the type of `symbol`. I am aware that this means that I'm using a name which is not defined in the place in which I'm attempting to use it, but I cannot see what is wrong with the code:

```
module MyData
(MetricUnit(..),
 ImperialUnit(..),
 Measurement(..),
 convert)
 where

data MetricUnit = Meter | Liter | KiloGram
              deriving (Show, Eq)

data ImperialUnit = Yard
                    | Gallon
                    | Pound
                      deriving (Show, Eq)

data Measurement = MetricMeasurement Double MetricUnit
             | ImperialMeasurement Double ImperialUnit
               deriving (Show)

symbol :: MetricUnit -> String
symbol Meter = "m"
symbol Liter = "L"
symbol KiloGram = "kg"

convert (MetricMeasurement x u)
     | u==Meter    = ImperialMeasurement (1.0936*x) Yard
     | u==Liter    = ImperialMeasurement (0.2642*x) Gallon
     | u==KiloGram = ImperialMeasurement (2.2046*x) Pound

convert (ImperialMeasurement x u)
      | u==Yard   = MetricMeasurement (0.9144*x) Meter
      | u==Gallon = MetricMeasurement (3.7854*x) Liter
      | u==Pound  = MetricMeasurement (0.4536*x) KiloGram
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering the context to this question, is here https://gist.github.com/BinRoot/4771288 . Please include the entire environment/file that you are feeding ghci with.

Comment: Was is always `convert, symbol)`, or did you add this to the code after [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63291414/12695027) by [chi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3234959) indicated you were missing it?

Comment: @Scratte I added this because Chi below had recommended it. It hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: @Edward.Lin I understand. But now, you've invalidated their Answer. I suggest you remove the `, symbol` part. You can add to the Question that you've used it as per an Answer, but you're still getting the same error.

Comment: @Scratte I'll take `convert, symbol)` out of my question. But adding `convert, symbol)` doesn't work, so can't be the solution.

Comment: @Edward.Lin doing `:load MyData` and then `:t symbol` into ghci correctly tells me `symbol :: MetricUnit -> String`, so it seems to work fine. You should clarify ***exactly*** the steps needed to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

When typing multi-line things in ghci (like type declarations, class definitions, `deriving` clauses on another line), you have to enter multi-line mode. You can enter `:{` which will put you in a multi-line prompt, then enter your code, then enter `:}` on another line to exit the multi-line prompt. Then, it'll interpret your code as one chunk instead of many lines.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is that your module starts in this way:

```
module MyData
    (MetricUnit(..),
     ImperialUnit(..),
     Measurement(..),
     convert)
where
```

hence, the function `symbol` is not exported by the module.

In GHCi, loading the module as `ghci MyData.hs` from the command line, or as `:load MyData` from the GHCi prompt should bypass the export list and give you access to everything.

You could also add `symbol` to the export list.

You are getting that error because (I guess) you are instead using another way to import your module that won't give you access to non-exported identifiers. Maybe you are importing that module though another one?

Comment: To add `symbol` to the export list would I simply have to substitute ``(..)`` next to `MetricUnit`` with ``(symbol)``, and add the definition of ``symbol`` after ``where``?

Comment: @Edward.Lin Change `convert)` to `convert, symbol)`

Comment: I added ``convert, symbol)`` and still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with "can not reproduce":

```
% cat <<EOF > ap.hs
heredoc> data MetricUnit = Meter | Liter | KiloGram
       deriving (Show, Eq)

symbol :: MetricUnit -> String
symbol Meter = "m"
symbol Liter = "L"
symbol KiloGram = "kg"
heredoc> EOF
tommd@ovdak /tmp% ghci ap.hs
GHCi, version 8.6.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded package environment from /Users/tommd/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-8.6.4/environments/default
package flags have changed, resetting and loading new packages...
Loaded GHCi configuration from /Users/tommd/.ghci
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ap.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main>
```

So it loads fine.

Perhaps you are trying to *define* the code in GHCi instead of load it from a file?  In the case see @Aplet123's answer about multi-lines. For an example of a broken use of GHCi, which you might be doing, consider:

```
*Main> foo :: Bool

<interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: foo :: Bool
*Main> foo = True
```

After the first line is entered, GHCi tries to show you foo (`print (foo :: Bool)`) and not having `foo` it will tell you foo is not in scope.  Again, see the other answer.

Comment: No, I'm not defining it in GHCI. I'm using a file. And deriving is on a separate line. The code is from here https://gist.github.com/BinRoot/4771288. It loads but when I ask for the type of symbol I receive the scope error.

Comment: @Edward.Lin Your code looks fine. Did you successfully load it in GHCi? Can you evaluate `Meter` successfully, for instance?

Comment: @Chi Yes I did. And Meter evaluates successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the result of there being another file with the same name.

The problem was resolved when I created a new file with a fresh file name.